# Wireshark loopback on mac os x

Tags: macos, http, wireshark

I have selected loopback (in capture options) to capture http traffic on my localhost server, but everytime I do and HTTP I only can see TCP.
[image]

Comment: What did you expect to see? UDP calls for DNS? ARP?

Comment: I want to see http traffic.

Comment: HTTP traffic usually uses TCP. If you want to see interpreted contents of the TCP packets (which might be HTTP request) then I suggest using webscarab or a similar proxy.  Right now you are looking a layer to low.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think i saw http traffic in the past, and I expected just a wrong configuration, actually  this issue only happens on loopback.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably that's because no process on the machine is sending UDP packets to another endpoint on the same machine.  Try doing `ping 127.0.0.1` while you're capturing on `lo0` and see whether ICMP packets show up (they do, at least on my Mountain Lion machine).

Comment: ping to 127.0.0.1 shows ICMP packets in my wireshark

Comment: Then you're not seeing UDP packets because nobody's sending them over the loopback interface - as Hennes indicated, there's probably no reason for UDP traffic to show up there.  If you're looking for HTTP traffic, that'll be *TCP* traffic.